# I can't fix the resolution on virtual box for ubuntu 14.04 The resolution is set to 2560x1965

Tags: virtualbox, resolv.conf

I need help in solving this problem. I have tried doing that through system settings but to no avail I cannot reach the part to change the resolution. Is there another way I can set it to another resolution?

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms` and install guest additions

Answer (score 0):

Run a terminal: Ctrl+Alt+t

and then write the following:

```
xrandr -s 1024x768
```

this will lower your resolution down to 1024x768.

To avoid this kind of problems install guest additions.